# How to convert RxSwift's Single to Observable and ignore `complete` event?

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

The case is following. 
I have a Single that I receive from a third-party API.
I want to transform this single to Observable, but the issue is Single transformed to Observable still completes my observable chain after emitting a value which I don't want to happen. I want that my observable never completes.

The question is is there any way easier than 'single.flatMap{ Observable.just($0)}' to do what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd love to see some more code, because `single.flatMap { Observable.just($0) }` will *not* stop a completion event from happening so if you think it does, then something's wrong.

Frankly, `.flatMap { Observable.just($0) }` does nothing at all, i.e., you could remove it completely and not change your code at all.

That said, the most obvious way to stop a completed event is `single.concat(Observable.never())`.